# Spring no mapea el controlador

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Al intentar acceder a la URL, el sistema esta arrojando `404`.

Se utiliza la siguiente `url`:

`http://localhost:8080/reserva/consultaporNUIP`

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Éste el es controlador.

```
@Controller
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(path = "/reserva")
public class ClienteWS {

    @Autowired
    private ClienteServicio clienteServicio;

    @RequestMapping(path="/consultaporNUIP", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity buscarPorCedula(@RequestParam int nuip) {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
        try {
            cliente = clienteServicio.consultarPorCedula(nuip);
            return new ResponseEntity(cliente, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity(cliente, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

    }

}
```

El Log:

```
2019-03-30 21:12:02.320  INFO 7272 --- [           main]             org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core     {5.3.7.Final}
2019-03-30 21:12:02.321  INFO 7272 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-03-30 21:12:02.474  INFO 7272 --- [           main]     o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons         Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-03-30 21:12:02.608  INFO 7272 --- [           main]         org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect:     org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2019-03-30 21:12:02.811  INFO 7272 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-03-30 21:12:03.014  INFO 7272 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-03-30 21:12:03.059  WARN 7272 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-03-30 21:12:03.272  INFO 7272 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-03-30 21:12:03.275  INFO 7272 --- [           main] c.h.r.aplicacion.ReservaApplication      : Started ReservaApplication in 3.41 seconds (JVM running for 3.753)
2019-03-30 21:12:05.839  INFO 7272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-03-30 21:12:05.840  INFO 7272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2019-03-30 21:12:05.847  INFO 7272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 7 ms
```

Comment: Te funcionan otros mapeos de la aplicación? La aplicación está en servidor (Tomcat, Jboss... )?

Comment: No me he funcionado con otros. Estoy utilizando Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucione el problema indicando a Spring cuales son los repositorios y entidades que debe cargar. Entonces se agrego las siguientes anotaciones.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "co.proyecto.aerolinea")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "co.proyecto.aerolinea.modelo")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "co.proyecto.aerolinea.dao")
```

Answer (score 1):

El endpoint `consultaporNUIP` esta esperando un `RequestParam`, por lo que el request debería ser algo así:

```
http://localhost:8080/reserva/consultaporNUIP?nuip=1
```

es decir, tienes que especificar el `nuip`

Comment: No me ha funcionado.

Comment: Eso provocaría un 400,no un 404.

Comment: Gracias tio, esto me ha servido!

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando un servidor, la aplicación se despliega con su nombre:

```
http://localhost:8080/nombreDeMiAplicacion/
```

Por lo que neceistas encontrar el nombre de la aplicación (está declarado en el fichero web.xml) para saber la URL completa, que será algo como

```
http://localhost:8080/<nombreDeMiAplicacion>/reserva/consultaporNUIP
```